# Swipe all items of recyclerview right at once like Snapchat

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I want to swipe right all recyclerview items, to reveal some more details.

Snapchat is doing that already with the messages to reveal message timestamp.

look at this example[image]

So how can i do this?

Comment: There's no built-in method. You will need to implement it yourself. I don't know how Snapchat does it, but you can probably drag the Recyclerview itself with a TouchEvent listener and reveal views below with the correct values.

Comment: Try SlidingPaneLayout